# Can $p(Y|a,b)$ ever be equal to $p(Y|a) \cdot p(Y|b)$?

Tags: probability, classification, bayesian, naive-bayes

This strikes me as a simple question, but in re-visiting how the Naive Classifier works I started wondering if there is **any** probabilistic model that under certain independency assumptions obtains:

$p(Y |  a,b) = p(Y|a) \cdot p(Y|b)$

This could be used, for example, to build a classifier that gets the class probability as the product of the conditional class probabilities (in the case above, $Y$ would be the class, and $a$ & $b$ the features).

Intuitively something tells me that this is doable, but if I try to find under what conditions I could reach the equation above, I don't get anywhere.

For example, if I asssume that $Y$ is independent of $b$, given $a$, I obviously simply get: $p(Y|a,b)  = p(Y|a)$ so I am missing the second term. I can't think of any independency assumptions that gives me the original equation. Is that because they don't exist?

Comment: It strikes me that the probability of drawing a card of a particular value and suit would satisfy this.

Comment: @Eric As long as you have a full deck ... (or at least, a deck where all values and suits are balanced).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation in the question only happens in the trivial case where both $p(Y|a)$ and $p(Y|b)$ are point masses on a single $Y$ value.  If it were true, then $\sum_Y p(Y|a) p(Y|b) = 1$.  However, consider the following bound:
$$
\sum_Y p(Y|a) p(Y|b) \leq \sum_Y p(Y|a) \max_{Y'} p(Y'|b) = \max_{Y'} p(Y'|b)
$$
For the LHS to be 1, there must be a value of Y for which $p(Y|b)=1$, which means that value of $Y$ is the only one possible.  By symmetry, this must also be true for $p(Y|a)$.

Comment: Thanks Tom. This is very helpful. I am probably missing something trivial, but why would $\sum_Y p(Y|a) p(Y|b) = 1$ not be possible?

Comment: @user023472: just change your equation to $\propto$, which is probably what you meant?

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible, only that it implies that $p(Y|b)$ (and by symmetry also $p(Y|a)$) is a point mass, which is not a very useful model.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Everything is now crystal clear. This is an elegant answer to a question that I always had. What I still don't understand is how this could be consistent with @NeilG's answer. If the condition in the original question only happens in the trivial case where there is only one $Y$ possible, how can the product of experts truly assume the equation in Neil's answer?

Comment: @user023472: Because I had assumed that you were going to renormalize not set as equal.  This also happens when $Y$ is an outcome rather than an event in e.g. a noisy-OR.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be non-interacting events yielding independent information about $Y$ and $Y$ has a uniform prior, then this is the only reasonable way of combining information.  Geoff Hinton calls this a *product of experts*.  One caveat, if $Y$ doesn't have a uniform prior, then you'll double-count it when you do the pointwise multiplication.  So you should really do $$P(Y\mid a,b) \propto \frac{p(Y\mid a) \cdot p(Y\mid b)}{p(Y)}$$.

Maybe you could say that the likelihoods induced on $a$ and $b$ are independent given $Y$?

Comment: Thanks -- This is very helpful -- I was somewhat familiar with the product of experts model. The only thing that isn't clear to me is how one gets the RHS from the LHS, i.e. the sequence of decompositions and assumptions that one makes from the LHS to reach the RHS.

Comment: If "likelihoods induced on a and b are independent given Y", then it should work.

Comment: If the expression is $\sim$, what is the point in having $p(Y)$ in the denominator? You could as well have any other constant, correct?

Comment: @user023472: Because $p(Y)$ might not be constant — it might depend on the value of $Y$.